# Cleveref (Cref) Format for Appendix

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, appendix

I wish to reference-call my sections in the style "(curly-S)2.1". Looking at the [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf), Section 8.2.1, I can achieve this as `\Crefformat{section}{\S#2#1#3}`. However, this doesn't work when the section is an appendix. There are lots of questions on cleveref+appendix, but I haven't been able to find a solution in them.

I can, of course, simply use `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}` and reset the counter. It feels like there should be a much better way...

---

Currently everything is set up as default for `article`.
The following is a simple MWE.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\Crefformat{section}{\S#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Section}
\label{main}
\appendix
\section{Appendix Section}
\label{app}

\Cref{main}

\Cref{app}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How are the section headers displayed at present? As `1 [title]`, `2 [title]`, ... `A [title]`, `B [title]`? Do you prefix the `\S` symbol to the section-level headers? ?  Which document class do you employ? Please be specific.

Comment: Everything is default, other than the one `\Crefformat{...}{...}` that I describe. I actually solved it anyway with a guess! (and answered below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't find this answer, I actually managed to guess it! Simply add `\Crefformat{appendix}{\S#2#1#3}`. Basically, the counter is just called `appendix` instead of `section`. See below.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\Crefformat{section}{\S#2#1#3}
\Crefformat{appendix}{\S#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Section}
\label{main}
\subsection{Main Subsectino}
\label{submain}

\appendix
\section{Appendix Section}
\label{app}
\subsection{Appendix Subsection}
\label{subapp}

\Cref{main}

\Cref{submain}

\Cref{app}

\Cref{subapp}

\end{document}
```